# Dialogflow retrieving data from Firebase Real time database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3, dialogflow-es, api-ai

Currently I'm working on a mobile app using Ionic and Angular2 with Realtime database service from firebase. I want to make a chatbot using Dialogflow to analyze the user request (i.e. I need a wheelchair) and then analyze the firebase db for any similar items stored, and if it exists, I need to show the item's name and the *uid* of the user who has added it into the database.

Have seen some tutorials on Dialogflow with Cloud Firestore but I'm not sure whether this works with the Realtime DB and how it would work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

To do this, you'll need to use a [fulfillment webhook](https://dialogflow.com/docs/fulfillment) that [will be sent the information](https://dialogflow.com/docs/fulfillment#request) about what the user has said, does the database search, and [sends the reply](https://dialogflow.com/docs/fulfillment#response) using Dialogflow's response JSON format.